# What do these errors mean in React-Native in my react-native project and how do I fix them?

Tags: android, react-native, npm

```
Error: spawn ./gradlew EACCES
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
```

0 info it worked if it ends with ok

1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'android' ]

2 info using npm@6.14.5

3 info using node@v12.17.0

4 verbose run-script [ 'preandroid', 'android', 'postandroid' ]

5 info lifecycle @~preandroid: @

6 info lifecycle @~android: @

7 verbose lifecycle @~android: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true

8 verbose lifecycle @~android: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/jonas/Desktop/ProjectTastebuds2/TasteBuds/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin

9 verbose lifecycle @~android: CWD: /Users/jonas/Desktop/ProjectTastebuds2/TasteBuds

10 silly lifecycle @~android: Args: [ '-c', 'react-native run-android' ]

11 silly lifecycle @~android: Returned: code: 1  signal: null

12 info lifecycle @~android: Failed to exec android script

13 verbose stack Error: @ android: `react-native run-android`

13 verbose stack Exit status 1

13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)

13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)

13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)

13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)

13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)

13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)

14 verbose pkgid @

15 verbose cwd /Users/jonas/Desktop/ProjectTastebuds2/TasteBuds

16 verbose Darwin 19.6.0

17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "android"

18 verbose node v12.17.0

19 verbose npm  v6.14.5

20 error code ELIFECYCLE

21 error errno 1

22 error @ android: `react-native run-android`

22 error Exit status 1

23 error Failed at the @ android script.

23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Answer (score 28):

Run

`cd android && ./gradlew clean`

`chmod +x gradlew`

It will work

Comment: This worked for me as well. I was facing this problem => Error: spawn ./gradlew EACCES

Comment: in my case i need to run first chmod +x gradlew

Comment: me too @MzkZeeshan, I had to change the permissions on the ./gradlew file first as well

Comment: Yes modifying permissions over gradlew works.
I used
`chmod 777 gradlew` 
and it worked too. 
Thanks

Answer (score 15):

```sh
cd android;
chmod +x gradlew;
./gradlew clean && cd ..;
```

It worked for me this way.

Comment: worked like charm!

Answer (score 1):

**Try This**

```
cd android

chmod +x gradlew
```

done

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux / Ubantu then you need give folder permission.
so you just need to type the command on your root Directory of project folder:
sudo chmod -R 777 folder_name

eg:kishan@kishan-ideacentre-588S-0554iKL:~/Workspace/HundredAcer$ sudo chmod -R 777 android

Then copy file named local properties from AndroidStudioProject/Your AppName/
then paste it to your projectName/Android/

you are done..!